# Scrapy CrawlerProcess does not override settings

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to run multiple scrapy crawlers with [CrawlerProcess](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess) with few custom settings.

```
settings = get_project_settings()
settings['TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED'] = False
settings['CONCURRENT_REQUESTS'] = 2
settings['CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN'] = 1
settings['DOWNLOAD_DELAY'] = 5
settings['LOG_LEVEL'] = 'DEBUG'

process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
process.crawl(QSpider)
process.start()
```

It works well. I can see settings getting overriden.

```
2022-02-09 12:23:39 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2022-02-09 12:23:39 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.7.1.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.1.0, Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
2022-02-09 12:23:39 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2022-02-09 12:23:39 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 2,
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5,
 'TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED': False}
....
2022-02-09 12:23:46 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (shutdown)
```

However when I pass a [Crawler](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.Crawler) instance to the crawl method like

```
..... # same settings
process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
process.crawl(Crawler(QSpider))
process.start()
```

Nothing gets overridden now. It does not even honor ***DOWNLOAD_DELAY***.

```
2022-02-09 12:32:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2022-02-09 12:32:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.7.1.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.1.0, Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
2022-02-09 12:32:11 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2022-02-09 12:32:11 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{}
2022-02-09 12:32:11 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password:
.....
2022-02-09 12:32:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

**Note:** Running Scrapy 2.5.1 on Python 3.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to override some settings, one way would be overriding/setting custom_settings, the spider's static variable, in our script.

so I imported the spider's class and then override the custom_setting:

```
from testspiders.spiders.followall import FollowAllSpider 
FollowAllSpider.custom_settings={'RETRY_TIMES':10}
```

So this is the whole script:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from testspiders.spiders.followall import FollowAllSpider 

FollowAllSpider.custom_settings={'RETRY_TIMES':10}
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())


# 'followall' is the name of one of the spiders of the project.
process.crawl('testspider', domain='scrapinghub.com')
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```